# View commits for a given directory at a particular date in Github

Tags: github

I want to view all the commits for a given "directory" and after a given date, in Github. I have read Github API documentation and "path"  and "since" parameters do the job. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository

However, I am not able to view them on Github. "Since" parameter seems not to work on Github. Example: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits?path=Documentation&since=2016-04-04T16:00:49Z

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Leticia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Command line:

  Use git log --since option.

  git log --since="2015-12-01"

  This will tell all commits/actions since December 01 2015. Checkout link
  [Git commit history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History#Limiting-Log-Output)

EDIT:

- Git hub:

  As per my research, there is no trivial solution to view github commits "after" a particular day. You can however use compare option to compare repo/branches between two time periods, this will give you a view of commits "after" particular day.

  E.g: The following compares branches between two time periods, thereby listing all commits between this period.

  [https://github.com/torvalds/linux/compare/master@{2016-04-14}...master@{2016-04-25}](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/compare/master@%7B2016-04-14%7D...master@%7B2016-04-25%7D)

  Hope, this helps!

  Note: I would recommend command line when possible as it definitely gives you more flexibility.

Comment: What I am asking is how to view them in Github, graphically. Not in git command line.

Comment: @leti88, Looks like Robert has provided a sample example. Please let us know, if you are still facing issue. Enjoy!

Comment: Thks. Any guess about how could I retrieve commits  "after" {date}?

Comment: @leti88, I have made an edit to my post. I understand its not a direct solution you are hoping, but I hope it helps you view all commits after particular time period.

Comment: If you wanna see it in reverse (oldest first) just pipe it with cat (e.g. `git log --since="2018-03-10" | cat`) and scroll up

Answer (score 3):

You could use either this:

```
git log -- path/ --since="date"
```

Or this to check a file history

```
 git log -- path/myfile.txt --since="date"
```

In github you would have to do this:

```
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master@{date}/Documentation
```

for your particular example:

```
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master@{2016-04-04T16:00:49Z}/Documentation
```

Comment: What I am asking is how to view them in Github, graphically. Not in git command line.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Roberto. Your approach gives return the commits which date is "before" {date}. How could i retrieve commits which date is "after" {date}? Thanks

Comment: @leti88 sorry I didn't reply you back. I had to ask github because I didn't know the answer to your problem either and they've just answered me. Hope it helps

Comment: Appreciate your effort :)

Comment: That GitHub URL is very useful, but there seems to be a limit to how far back it can go if there are a lot of commits. Take this for instance: [https://github.com/google/fonts/commits/main@{2016-04-04T16:00:49Z}](https://github.com/google/fonts/commits/main@{2016-04-04T16:00:49Z}) ... As of writing, this will only go as far back as April 2021.